# Cast Option[Any] to int

Tags: scala

How do I cast this to an Int and not `Some(Int)`

```
val a: Option[Any] = Some(1)
```

I tried `toInt` and it gave an error `value toInt is not a member of Option[Any]`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could do `a.get.asInstanceOf[Int]` however it is unsafe. A better way would be to retain the type information i.e. using a `Option[Int]` instead of an `Option[Any]`. Then you would not need to cast the result with `asInstanceOf`.

```
val a:Option[Int] = Some(1)
val i = a.get
```

Using `get` directly is unsafe since if the `Option` is a `None` an exception is thrown. So using `getOrElse` is safer. Or you could use pattern matching on `a` to get the value.

```
val a:Option[Any] = Some(1) // Note using Any here
val i = (a match {
  case Some(x:Int) => x // this extracts the value in a as an Int
  case _ => Int.MinValue
})
```

Comment: Forget the bit about casting; pattern matching is clearly the way to go

Comment: I agree. Pattern matching is very powerful and awesome :)

Answer (score 15):

Using `.asInstanceOf` method

```
a.getOrElse(0).asInstanceOf[Int]
```

I have to note that this is *unsafe* cast: if your Option contains not Int, you'll get runtime exception.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you can't cast it is because you are not supposed to cast.  While static typed programming languages allows you to manually cast between one type and the other, the best suggestion I can give you is to forget about this features.

In particularly, if you want to get the best out of each programming language, try to make a proper user, and if a language does not fit the usage you want just choose another one (such as a dynamically typed one):

> If you make casts you turn a potential compile time error, which we
>   like because it's easy to solve, into a ClassCastException, which we
>   don't like because it occurs at runtime. If you need to use casts in
>   Scala, very likely you are using an improper pattern.

Comment: While I do appreciate the sentiment, in real life projects, things aren't always as black and white. There is a legitimate need for me to do this as it could be one of 4 types returned by the underlying 3rd party API.

Comment: This is a very weak mechanism. You can get the same done with better patterns probably... Why don't you try to explain what you want to do?