# Change type of an array element

Tags: scala

How could I convert the following array to one of type Array[(Long, Long, Long)]

```
Array[(Any, Long, Long)] = Array((20090216,152,2743012), (20090711,83,2743012))
```

I have tried mapping the first element `test.map(x => (x._1).toLong)`

but I get

> error: value toLong is not a member of Any

Comment: Possible duplicate and the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11716183/4105457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is incomplete. Why is the first tuple element's type `Any` in the first place, and how are we supposed to know how to convert it to a Long? The answer may be wildly different depending on the run-time type of that object.

Kao did also not answer the question, which was how to turn it into an `Array[(Long, Long, Long)]`, not `Array[Long]`.
There are essentially two ways to do that. Use the copy method:

```
test map {x => x.copy(_1 = x._1.…)}
```

Or use a partial function literal:

```
test map {case (x,y,z) => (x.…, y, z)}
```

While the former is slightly more terse, the latter gives you additional possibilites. You can for instance use the `collect` method, removing elements that you can't convert, or you can handle different types of values, say, BigInt and BigInteger:

```
test collect {
    case (x: BigInt, y, z) => (x.longValue, y, z)
    case (x: BigInteger, y, z) => (x.longValue, y, z)
}
```

(Note: this code will return bogus values if the BigInts don't actually fit into a long, so one should check for that in production code.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler what type the `Any` element, you're trying to map is. You can do this by using `asInstanceOf`.

```
val t: Array[(Any, Long, Long)] = Array((20090216,152,2743012), (20090711,83,2743012))
t.map(x=> x._1.asInstanceOf[Number].longValue)
```

This outputs:

```
Array[Long] = Array(20090216, 20090711)
```

You would probably need to guard this in a `Try`, to make sure you don't get casting exceptions.

**Edit:** 
If you solely wish to have an array of Type `(Long, Long, Long)` the easiest way is to just transform the entire array. Now again, you should wrap this in a `Try`.

```
val t: Array[(Any, Long, Long)] = Array((20090216,152,2743012), (20090711,83,2743012))
val x = t.asInstanceOf[Array[(Long, Long, Long)]]
```

This outputs:

```
Array[(Long, Long, Long)] = Array((20090216,152,2743012), (20090711,83,2743012))
```

Comment: *Bad Idea*. Wrapping the cast in a `Try{}` won't help, because the cast operation "succeeds" due to erasure regardless of whether there are *actually* Longs in that tuple. The array doesn't know at runtime what the types of the tuple elements are, it only knows it's dealing with some Tuple3. So when you cast, it just ignores Tuple3's type parameters and hopes for the best. `Try { (1, 2l, 3l).asInstanceOf[(Long, Long, Long)] }.toOption.map(_._1)` will not evaluate to `None` but result in a ClassCastException.