# How to cast (Any)? to Int

Tags: swift, downcast

I am trying to cast a (Any)? value to a Integer. I am retrieving information from Firebase and I want to add the number by something else. That is why the (Any)? value needs to be a Integer. I have this:

```
let snapshotValues = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
let gamesWon = snapshotValues!.value(forKey: "GamesWon")
let gamesLost = snapshotValues!.value(forKey: "GamesLost")
let totalgamesPlayedByUser = gamesWon + gamesLost
```

This is giving me an error that two Any? objects can not be added together. I already tried the Int(gamesWon), gamesWon as! Int, but that did not work. How to cast this as a Integer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast Option\[Any\] to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716081/cast-optionany-to-int)

Answer (score 6):

If you know that both keys contain `Int`s, you should be able to write

```
let gamesWon = snapshotValues!.value(forKey: "GamesWon") as! Int
let gamesLost = snapshotValues!.value(forKey: "GamesLost") as! Int
```

making `gamesWon + gamesLost` a valid `Int` expression.

If you are *not* sure if the keys are there or not, use `if let` statements instead:

```
if let gamesWon = snapshotValues!.value(forKey: "GamesWon") as? Int {
    if let gamesLost = snapshotValues!.value(forKey: "GamesLost") as? Int {
        let totalgamesPlayedByUser = gamesWon + gamesLost
    }
}
```

Comment: change the answer to use if let statements, so the app doesn't crash

Comment: From Swift 1.2 on, You can use a single `let` statement: `if let gamesWon=..., let gamesLost=... {...}`.

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively:

```
var gamesWon  : Any = 1
var gamesLost : Any = 2
var totalGamesPlayedByUser : Int

if gamesWon is Int && gamesLost is Int {
   totalGamesPlayedByUser = gamesWon as! Int + gamesLost as! Int
}
```